# Input voltage/current required for LM1117 3.3 Power Regulator

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power, basic

Can I use **Mobile charger** having **Output Rating of Voltage 6.0V / Current 300mA** as input to LM1117 3.3 Chip.

> If possible - Will it be able to provide 800mA current when
>   required and how?

Comment: You'll need to determine if what you have is a `battery charger`, a `constant voltage supply` or a `moving target supply`.  Today's USB "phone chargers" are crude approximations to a constant voltage supply, with the charge regulation done in the phone.  But other approaches exist, with the charge regulation done in the adapter (which would not be useful as a general power supply) and with poorly- or un-regulated adapters which again may not be suitable as power supplies as their voltage may change too much under load.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can power an LM1117 from your power supply.
The droput voltage is 1.2 V so...  1.2 + 3.3 = 4.5 V ....you have 0.5 V headroom.

It will NOT provide 800mA at 3.3 V since this is a linear regulator, Iout = Isupply.
You will be able to get a maximum of 300 mA since that is what your power supply is rated at.

Comment: What will be Max Output Current of LM1117 3.3v if give it 5v/1mA as input. According to datasheet LM1117 3.3v Output Current is 800mA. Help me understand.

Comment: This is a linear regular, thus the input current is always identical with the output current.

Comment: Will using input current higher than 800mA have any -/ve impact on power supply

Comment: If you have a power supply rated at 300 mA maximum.....then one can assume that at some point not far beyond 300 mA the voltage will collapse and it may shutdown. If you want 800 mA....buy an 800 mA or above power supply.

Comment: The output current is always *less* than the input current, however that consumed by the regulator itself is small enough that it may be neglected in some quick estimates.  It's definitely an issue if running on battery though, and may be when cutting close to the supply specification.

Comment: You are absolutely right Chris I completely disregarded the 120 microamps of regulator current for the adjust/gnd pin ....the OP should remember to subtract this from his output current of 800 mA!